# iterating over a json with json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I have json which has a structure like below :

```
{
"searchResults": {
    "searchCriteria": {
        "location": {
            "originalLocation": null
        },
        "startAndEndDate": {
            "start": "2016-10-06T00:00:00",
            "end": "2016-10-09T00:00:00"
        },

        "solution": [{
                "resultID": "O1MDc1MD",
                "selected": false,
                "charges": {
                    "localCurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "averagePricePerNight": 153
                },
                "starRating": 3.5
            },

            {
                "resultID": "0MDc1MD",
                "selected": false,
                "charges": {
                    "localCurrencyCode": "USD",
                    "averagePricePerNight": 153
                },
                "starRating": 3.5
            }
        ]

    }
}
}
```

I have a case class like :

```
case class ResponseModel(
//localCurrencyCode: Option[String],
averagePricePerNight: Option[Int],
starRating: Option[Int])
```

I want to extract the values of averagePricePerNight and starRating and return it in a List.

I am not able to get a list which includes both starRating and averagePricePerNight as within the solution array I have one more array of charges and so I dont get a List.

I used:

```
val messagesIds = (json \\ "solution") \ "starRating"

println(messagesIds.values) 

Output: List(3.5, 3.5, 3.0)
```

Expected Output :

```
List(ResponseModel(5.0,900), ResponseModel(4.5,100), ResponseModel(4.5,1000))
```

and it gives me a list of StarRatings alone. How can I combine both and let me know if another library can do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for something like

```
case class Charges(localCurrencyCode: String, averagePricePerNight: Int)
case class Solution(resultID: String, selected: Boolean, charges: Charges, starRating: Double)

val parsed = (parse(json) \\ "solution").extract[List[Solution]]

val result = parsed.map(x => ResponseModel(Some(x.charges.averagePricePerNight), Some(x.starRating)))
```

Note 1: `starRating` seems to be a `Double` not an `Int`

Note 2: your `ResponseModel` uses `Option`s... but your expected seems not to.

Comment: Without the option the code was failing, I will just give this a try.

Comment: getting type mismatch error  on your line 3: Type Mismatch : org.json4s.Jvalue (which expands to) on org.JsonAst.json4s required org.json4s.JsonInput

Comment: What is your line 3? What imports have you got there?